# Having one and only one Collection Data provider for each resource is a must?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

I do need custom operation in my API which returns an entity for given slug. Consequently, the total number of operations for the resource `Product` are 6 (5 are default operations + 1 custom operation).

```
  api_products_get_collection             GET        ANY      ANY    /api/products.{_format}                
  api_products_post_collection            POST       ANY      ANY    /api/products.{_format}                
  api_products_get_item                   GET        ANY      ANY    /api/products/{id}.{_format}           
  api_products_put_item                   PUT        ANY      ANY    /api/products/{id}.{_format}           
  api_products_delete_item                DELETE     ANY      ANY    /api/products/{id}.{_format}           
  api_products_slug                       GET        ANY      ANY    /api/products/by-slug/{slug}
```

I followed the [official documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers) to define the custom operation. But surprisingly, I noticed that the route `api_products_get_collection` is using the collection data provider of the route `api_products_slug`.

I thought at first it is problem of routes order. But, it was not the case since as it is shown in the command below:

```
$ bin/console debug:router | grep products 
  app_product_products                    ANY        ANY      ANY    /                                      
  api_products_get_collection             GET        ANY      ANY    /api/products.{_format}                
  api_products_post_collection            POST       ANY      ANY    /api/products.{_format}                
  api_products_get_item                   GET        ANY      ANY    /api/products/{id}.{_format}           
  api_products_put_item                   PUT        ANY      ANY    /api/products/{id}.{_format}           
  api_products_delete_item                DELETE     ANY      ANY    /api/products/{id}.{_format}           
  api_products_slug                       GET        ANY      ANY    /api/products/by-slug/{slug}
```

In addition, here is how I declared the routes:

```
api_platform:
    resource: .
    type: api_platform
    prefix: /api

# the routes is declared after the routes of the api_platfom to make sure having to the custom operation route after api_platfom routes
actions:
    resource: ../../src/Action/
    type: annotation
```

So, for sure, it is not a problem related to the order of routes.

The question is: **should I have one  and only one Collection Data Provider for each resource?**

---

Below is how I declared the custom operation.

**(1) Declaration of a provider implementing CollectionDataProviderInterface**

```
<?php

namespace App\Provider;

use App\Entity\Product;
use ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider\CollectionDataProviderInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Exception\ResourceClassNotSupportedException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

use App\Repository\ProductRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Monolog\Logger;

final class ProductCollectionDataProvider implements CollectionDataProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ProductRepository
     */
    private $repository;

    /**
     * @var RequestStack
     */
    private $requestStack;

    /**
     * @var Logger
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * ProductCollectionDataProviderconstructor.
     *
     * @param ProductRepository $repository
     * @param RequestStack $requestStack
     * @param Logger $logger
     */
    public function __construct(ProductRepository $repository, RequestStack $requestStack, Logger $logger)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a collection.
     *
     * @param string      $resourceClass
     * @param string|null $operationName
     *
     * @throws ResourceClassNotSupportedException
     *
     * @return array|\Traversable
     */
    public function getCollection(string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null){

        $this->logger->info('getCollection() is called');
        $slug =  $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->attributes->get('slug');
        $this->logger->info($slug);

        if (Product::class !== $resourceClass) {
            throw new ResourceClassNotSupportedException();
        }
        // if($operationName !== 'product_slug') return null;

        $product = $this->repository->findProductBySlug($this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->attributes->get('slug'));
        if($product===null){
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('The Product resource \'%s\' was not found.',$slug));

        }
        return $product;

    }

}
```

**(2) Definition of an action**

```
<?php

namespace App\Action;

use App\Entity\Product;
use App\Provider\ProductCollectionDataProvider;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class ProductSlug
{
    private $productCollectionDataProvider;

    public function __construct(ProductCollectionDataProvider $productCollectionDataProvider)
    {
        $this->productCollectionDataProvider = $productCollectionDataProvider;
    }

    /**
     * @Route(
     *     name="api_products_slug",
     *     path="/api/products/by-slug/{slug}",
     *     defaults={"_api_resource_class"=Product::class, "_api_collection_operation_name"="product_slug"}
     * )
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function __invoke()
    {
        return  $this->productCollectionDataProvider->getCollection(Product::class);
    }
}
```

**(3) declaration of the custom action as an service**

```
services:
    # ...
    App\Action\:
        resource: '../src/Action'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

**(4) declaration of the route of the custom action**

```
api_platform:
    resource: .
    type: api_platform
    prefix: /api

# the routes is declared after the routes of the api_platfom to make sure having to the custom operation route after api_platfom routes
actions:
    resource: ../../src/Action/
    type: annotation
```

**environment**

```
$ composer info | grep api
api-platform/api-pack             v1.0.1             A pack for API Platform
api-platform/core                 v2.1.5             The ultimate solution to create web APIs.
$ composer info | grep symfony/framework
symfony/framework-bundle          v4.0.4             Symfony FrameworkBundle
```

Comment: Is your data provider called? Or only the Doctrine one? Maybe should you change the priority of your data provider to make it higher than the built-in one?

Comment: There were a discussion on [github](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/550). I will be using controller to ease things.